# Angular filter - with controllerAs syntax not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this in html code:

```
<md-list>
  <md-list-item ng-repeat="schema in dash.filteredSchemas = (dash.items | filter: {name: dash.schemaListFilter}) | orderBy: 'schema.id'">
    <h4>{{ ::schema.name }}</h4>
  </md-list-item>
</md-list>
<div ng-show="dash.filteredSchemas.length">Empty</div>
```

The problem is that I don't see any results when using this syntax - where 10 results should be shown if filter in not filled.

Note: no console errors. Changing to:

```
<md-list>
  <md-list-item ng-repeat="schema in dash.items | filter: {name: dash.schemaListFilter} | orderBy: 'schema.id'">
    <h4>{{ ::schema.name }}</h4>
  </md-list-item>
</md-list>
<div ng-show="dash.filteredSchemas.length">Empty</div>
```

Shows results but (obviously) not shows the empty message when filter applied and no result match.

What is wrong with that?!

Comment: how do u set dash.filteredSchemas on second example?

Comment: I don't, it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want get filtered result but do not want to break original array you can use `'as'` operation for `ng-repeat`...

```
<md-list>
  <md-list-item ng-repeat="schema in dash.items | filter: {name: dash.schemaListFilter} | orderBy: 'schema.id' as filteredData">
    <h4>{{ ::schema.name }}</h4>
  </md-list-item>
</md-list>
<div ng-show="filteredData.length">Empty</div>
```

so whenever you change your filter query the result will be set to **'filteredData'** so you can use this array properties to achieve what you want...

Comment: Thanks, but how can I bind filteredData alias to my controller? meaning that I would be able to use it in other places like `dash.filteredData`?

Comment: if you really wants to set it on your vm alias you can watch its value as it is an element of scope...